# Formula or VBA code to calculate breakdown of difficult Hrs and Minutes working

Tags: excel, formula, vba

I am trying to calculate the length of each business travel leg for each of the country below. (B39:B42)

I need to show the time someone has spent in each separate location (C39:C42) based on the data provided between (A17:J22)

I have found a way to calculate the total time spent with the following formula in L23

```
=MAX(0,((LOOKUP(2,1/(I17:I22<>""),I17:I22)+LOOKUP(2,1/(J17:J22<>""),J17:J22))-(C17+D17))*24)
```

The formula picks up the last "date & Time" of Arrival and subtract the "date & Time" of Departure which gives the total of hours and minutes spent away. 
The problem is that I can't find a way to calculate the breakdown of time spent in each country/city. I have added a helper column "A" with a location number but still couldn't get the answer I am looking for because the tricky part is that each business trip leg might have a stopover that shouldn’t be calculated separately.

[image: Sample Business travel x4]

Can anyone guide me towards a way of fixing this? Either with a formula or a VBA code. Ideally would like the users to be able to allocate a number in ascending order using the helper column and get the breakdown per number between C39 and C42.

Many thanks in advance for any tips you may have.

Abby

Comment: So what cells should be subtracted from which cells for location 1?  Could you write out the desired subtraction values and expected result for the first location?

Comment: Hello Scott, When there are multiple locations, the business trip number 1 ends at the time the person leaves that location. In my example above for location 1, that would be Madrid/Spain with 60.8 hrs. Calculated as (08/10/2015 ; 07:25) – (05/10/2015 ; 18:40). That is because it is a multiple stop business trip. 

If for that same example the business trip was to Madrid and back to London only, (instead of going to paris on so on) it would have been 62.2 hours calculated as (08/10/2015 ; 08:50) – (05/10/2015 ; 18:40) 

I hope this makes sense…